# Com0Com create ports from command prompt

Tags: com0com

How to create virtual ports with Com0com command prompt with specific port name?

For example, I need to create COM11 and COM15. When I run next command if there are not any virtual ports it creates ports COM3 and COM4

```
install RealPortName=COM11 RealPortName=COM15
```

And when I run this command for other ports (`install RealPortName=COM12 RealPortName=COM13`) it creates ports COM5 and COM6.

So, It gives numbers in strict order. Is there any option to set port name strictly?

This is needed as I'm calling com0com command prompt from .Net application.

Answer (score 1):

Try just `PortName`, not `RealPortName`.